# crash cause by memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using an app that needs a lot of apps 
and I get each image by
 `[uiimage image with content of file ]`
then release the images  view did Disappear
by method

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    for (CALayer* layer in [self.view.layer sublayers])
    {
        [layer removeAllAnimations];
    }
}
```

after a while the app raise a memory earning issue and crash 
Any help will be appreciated

[image: my profiler screenshot]

Comment: Did you checked your app in Profiler for memory leaks?

Comment: Actually, check for leaks first with Analyzer, then Profiler.  Also, make use of the simulator's ability to simulate a memory warning and make sure that any code you have to handle that is working correctly.

Comment: @HotLicks 
i have the same problem and i check memory leaks and their is no leak

Comment: I've added my profiler screenshot to my original question

Comment: Did you check for heap growth using the "mark generation" tool?

Answer (score 0):

CALayer removeAllAnimations does not remove images from the layer; it removes layer animations. Completely different beast.

Comment: how can i remove images from the layer ?

Comment: i think my problem that when i call [self performSegueWithIdentifier@""]; dosen't release the sourceViewController or The old one because the memory graph in instrument is always increasing and i try all way to put all pointer with nil and all images with nil and no result any suggestion

Comment: You should be running in the analyzer looking for leaks. Each leak will show where it comes from.

Comment: i run the analyser and no leaks appear !!